# Mudar uma imagem a cada clique

Tags: javascript, html, css

Bom pessoal, estou com um problema aqui. Procurei várias vezes aqui no site e na internet e não tive uma resposta que me ajudasse o suficiente, ainda tenho dúvidas.

Estou com um site e tenho setores "collapsible", daí pra exemplificar, gostaria de colocar uma seta apontada para cima e quando clicasse, apontasse para baixo, ou tanto faz.
Eu consegui fazer isso, porém, só uma vez, se eu clico de novo, a imagem fica para baixo e não troca mais até atualizar a página.
Eu coloquei a imagem no começo do texto, logo abaixo tenho um exemplo.

Na verdade, o que eu queria mesmo, era que ela mudasse quando eu clicasse em qualquer parte do título do item "collapsible", mas por enquanto só consegui que ela mudasse quando eu clicasse nela.

Enfim, são duas perguntas no caso.
Como eu faço pra ela ficar em "loop" e toda vez que eu clicar ela trocar?
e
Como faço para que ela acione ao clicar no título também??

Coloquei o código javascript junto pra facilitar meus testes, a ideia é passar para outro arquivo depois.
Eu sou iniciante, tenho experiência com HTML e CSS, mas javascript é bem básico, estou relembrando muito de HTML e CSS com esse projeto que fazia tempo que não mexia e gostaria de uma jauda. Agradeço muito!

HTML com código Javascript junto:

```html
<div class="card">
   <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
  <h1 class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo" ng-click="alert_step2()">

  <img id="example" onclick="changeImage()" src="assets/img/arrow_up.png" width="20" height="25">

  <script>
  function changeImage(){         
           element=document.getElementById('example')
              if (element.src.match("out")){
           
                 element.src="assets/img/arrow_up.png";
              }
              else{
           
                 element.src="assets/img/arrow_down.png";
              }

              changeImage.repeat(100);
          }
   </script>
         Step 2 - Acknowledge Your Strengths (highest scores)
       
          </h1>
      </h5>
   </div>
</div>
```

```
                      <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                      <h5 class="mb-0">
                        <h1 class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo" ng-click="alert_step2()">


                                <h1 class="change"><img class="change img-change" src="assets/img/arrow_up.png" style="width: 20px; height: 25px">Step 2 - Acknowledge Your Strengths (highest scores)</h1>
```

Lembrando que o script que o Mateus Veloso me passou está em baixo desse collapse

Código atualizado:

```
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                      <h5 class="mb-0">


                                <script>
                                $('.change').click((e) => {
                                  var img1 = 'assets/img/arrow_up.png';
                                  var img2 = 'assets/img/arrow_down.png';
                                  var element = $('.img-change');
                                  if(element.attr('src') === img1){
                                    element.attr('src',img2);
                                  }else if(element.attr('src') === img2){
                                    element.attr('src',img1);
                                  }
                                });
                                </script>


                       <h1 class="collapsed change" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo" ng-click="alert_step2()"> <img class="change img-change" src="assets/img/arrow_up.png" style="width: 20px; height: 25px">Step 2 - Acknowledge Your Strengths (highest scores)</h1>

                        </h1>
                      </h5>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiz um exemplo funcional, acho que é possível você ter uma ideia de como fazer observando ele, o exemplo que criei é bem simples, caso precise de algo mais complexo pode comentar abaixo.

```js
$('.change').click((e) => {
  var img1 = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIerE.png';
  var img2 = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/cinkW.png';
  var element = $('.img-change');
  if(element.attr('src') === img1){
    element.attr('src',img2);
  }else if(element.attr('src') === img2){
    element.attr('src',img1);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="change">Testando Click</h1>
<img class="change img-change" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIerE.png">
```

Exemplo com javascript puro!

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('change');
elements[0].addEventListener("click", click);
elements[1].addEventListener("click", click);

function click(){
  var img1 = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIerE.png';
  var img2 = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/cinkW.png';
  var element = document.getElementById('img-change');
  if(element.src === img1){
    element.src = img2;
  }else if(element.src === img2){
    element.src = img1;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="change">Testando Clique</h1>
<img class="change" id="img-change" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIerE.png">
```

Comment: Acho que ele quer com Javascript puro.

Comment: @LeAndrade vou criar outro exemplo então!

Comment: Feito @LeAndrade

Comment: Estou com outra dúvida Mateus, primeiramente Obrigado! Segundo, eu coloquei o código e fiz as mudanças necessárias, porém, o collapse não abre mais, está funcionando a troca de imagem, mas não expande e mostra as informações escondidas mais, como posso resolver?

Comment: @EduardoBacarin lembrando que seu collapse deve continuar com todas as tags de antes, o ideal seria ver como está esse seu trecho de código, poste seu collapse atual!

Comment: <h1 class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo" ng-click="alert_step2()"> a classe e todos os atributos devem ser mantidos nesse caso

Comment: Vou postar o código do collapse aqui.

Comment: Está feito Mateus, se puder dar uma olhada, agradeceria. Eu não modifiquei ele, apenas coloquei o script e ele parou de funcionar

Comment: @EduardoBacarin olá, apague o <h1> : <h1 class="change"><img class="change img-change" src="assets/img/arrow_up.png" style="width: 20px; height: 25px">Step 2 - Acknowledge Your Strengths (highest scores)</h1> e adicione a classe change no collapse que está acima, ficando dessa forma : <h1 class="collapsed change" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo" ng-click="alert_step2()">

Comment: O problema é que voce criou um novo h1 entende ? o seu antigo que recebe o click para expandir seu conteudo, é simplesmente copiar tudo do de cima ou apagar o de baixo!

Comment: Eu simplesmente copiei o que vocÊ postou e colei, e não tá dando certo, eu acho que to errando em algo mais simples, como chamar o arquivo JS ou alguma coisa assim, to realmente quebrando a cabeça com isso... Eu que não to sabendo como montar tudo :/

Comment: Calma jovem faça a alteração que te pedi que vai funcionar

Comment: Faça exatamente isso,   <h1 class="collapsed change" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo" ng-click="alert_step2()">


                                <img class="change img-change" src="assets/img/arrow_up.png" style="width: 20px; height: 25px">Step 2 - Acknowledge Your Strengths (highest scores)</h1>

Comment: Ta ai o código que vai por no lugar, perceba que apaguei a <h1 que voce adicionou e colquei a variavel change na h1 que ja existia , entendeu ?

Comment: Eu acho que eu fiz do jeito que você falou, Mateus. Perdão a dificuldade hahaha, to tentando aprender direito ainda... Eu coloquei o código atualizado, da maneira como você me falou, copiei e substituí. Olha alí por favor. Inclusive coloquei o script ali pra você poder ver. O que tem de errado? A seta aparece, o collapse funciona, mas ela não troca a imagem.

Comment: Sem problemas @EduardoBacarin , a tag <script> tem que ficar abaixo , o problema é esse , provavelmente está gerando um erro de javascript porque no momento da execução do seu script o elemento ainda nao foi criado na pagina, entendeu ? jogue a tag <script>....</script> lá pro final da pagina que irá funcionar

Comment: Cara do céu! Você me ajudou com um problema que eu tava o dia inteiro aqui tentando! Muitíssimo obrigado de verdade! Obrigado pela paciência e pelas dicas! Um abraço enorme pra ti!

Comment: Se minha resposta te ajudou, avalia ela com o verdinho haha, obrigado a você! @EduardoBacarin

Comment: Eu não sei mexer muito na plataforma ainda, mas acho que foi, certo?

Comment: Deu certo sim haha, obrigado! precisando ....

Comment: Mateus, voltei! hahahha Tive um probleminha. Eu tenho que fazer isso em 12 collapses, quando fui por no segundo, ao testar, quando eu clico no segundo colapse, a imagem de seta do primeiro troca junto, ou seja, as duas fotos trocam juntos independente de qual eu clicar, o que posso fazer? Eu troquei o collapsetwo pra trhee, e o alert_step2 pra alert_step3, nada mudou.

Comment: Isso seria um topico para outra pergunta, como fazer isso de uma forma funcional e simples, faça a pergunta e mande o link aqui, irei lá na hora e criarei o código pra te ajudar!

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/339020/imagem-de-collapse-abrindo-duplicada ta aí Mateus, obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente você está usando o [collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/collapse/) do Bootstrap juntamente com o componente [card](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/card/).

Se for o caso, o collapse mostra/esconde os elementos através de classes:

- No elemento que é escondido são adicionadas as classes:

  - `.collapse` para esconder o conteúdo;
  - `.collapsing` durante a transição;
  - `.collapse.show` para mostrar o conteúdo
- No elemento que ativa o collapse:

  - `.collapsed` quando o elemento está escondido

Dito isso, com CSS você já sabe se o elemento está mostrando ou escondido através da presença ou ausência da classe `collapsed` no ativador. Dessa maneira você pode usar outros artifícios do CSS para adicionar as setas no `.card-header` e transformar o `.card-header` inteiro no ativador do *accordeon*.

Exemplo:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne" 
        data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne">
        <h5>Card title</h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show">
        <div class="card-body">Card content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Snippet utilizando o pseudo seletor [`:after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) juntamente com a propriedade [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) para criar os indicadores de estado:

```css
.card-header {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card-header:after {
  content: '▲';
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}

.card-header.collapsed:after {
  content: '▼';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="container">
    <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header bg-primary text-white" id="headingOne" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne">
                <h5 class="mb-0">Collapsible Group Item #1</h5>
            </div>

            <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                <div class="card-body">
                    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header collapsed bg-primary text-white" id="headingTwo" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo">
                <h5 class="mb-0">Collapsible Group Item #2</h5>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse"data-parent="#accordionExample">
                <div class="card-body">
                    3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header collapsed bg-primary text-white" id="headingThree" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree">
                <h5 class="mb-0">Collapsible Group Item #3</h5>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                <div class="card-body">
                    Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, Fernando, mas eu acho que o problema ta na pecinha aqui na frente do computador. Estou com muitas dificuldades pra fazer isso funcionar no sistema, fiz em uma página em branco pra ver como é e tá tudo ok... Peguei o sistema já muito avançado, não to sabendo mexer direito ainda. Mas agradeço muito pela ajuda! Vou continuar tentando pra ver o que consigo fazer

Comment: hahaha... Blz, boa sorte aí Eduardo!