# Imagem de collapse abrindo duplicada

Tags: javascript, html, css

Há pouco tempo consegui resolver um problema de colocar uma imagem e quando clicasse nela, ela se tornasse outra, e quando fui passar o código para os outros collapses, me aconteceu isso:

Collapse fechado
[image: collapse closed]

Collapse 3 (Step 3) aberto apenas
[image: collapse open]

Quando clico no Step 2 ou no Step 3, as duas setas (que são imagens) trocam juntas, eu preciso fazer isso em mais 12 steps, só que elas tem que trocar de maneira independente, como posso fazer?

Código Step 2:

```
<h1 class="collapsed change" 
    data-toggle="collapse" 
    data-parent="#accordion" 
    href="#collapseTwo" 
    aria-expanded="false" 
    aria-controls="collapseTwo" 
    ng-click="alert_step2()"> 
    <img class="change img-change" src="assets/img/arrow_right.png" style="width: 20px; height: 25px">Step 2 - Acknowledge Your Strengths (highest scores)
</h1>
```

Código Step 3:

```
<h1 class="collapsed change" 
    data-toggle="collapse" 
    data-parent="#accordion" 
    href="#collapseThree" 
    aria-expanded="false" 
    aria-controls="collapseThree" 
    ng-click="alert_step3()">
    <img class="change img-change" src="assets/img/arrow_right.png" style="width: 20px; height: 25px">Step 3 - Consider The Areas of Your Life that Need Support (lowest scores)
</h1>
```

Código Javascript:

```
$('.change').click((e) => {
    var img1 = 'assets/img/arrow_right.png';
    var img2 = 'assets/img/arrow_down.png';
    var element = $('.img-change');
    if(element.attr('src') === img1)
    {
        element.attr('src',img2);
    }
    else if(element.attr('src') === img2)
    {
        element.attr('src',img1);
    }
});
```

Comment: Posta seu código, só com a imagem não da para te ajudar. Mas provavelmente os seus dois elementos tem o mesmo ID="" ai da pau mesmo

Comment: postado! havia esquecido

Comment: Irei postar a resposta com o código corrigido!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma alternativa simples é adicionar um atributo "index" e alterar apenas o do mesmo index de onde veio o click, aqui vai um exemplo funcional:

```js
    $('.change').click(function (){
      var img1 = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIerE.png';
      var img2 = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/cinkW.png';
      var index = $(this).attr('index');
      var element = $('img[index='+index+']');
      if(element.attr('src') === img1){
        element.attr('src',img2);
      }else if(element.attr('src') === img2){
        element.attr('src',img1);
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 index="1" class="change">Testando Click</h1>
    <img index="1" class="change img-change" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIerE.png">
    <br>
    <h1 index="2" class="change">Testando Click</h1>
    <img index="2" class="change img-change" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIerE.png">
```

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado Mateus!